# How to disable textarea using angularjs when selected option value matches the condition?

Tags: html, angularjs

i am new to angularjs. I want to disable the textarea when one of my option is selected from a dropdown.

I tried with ng-disabled="(here my ng-model value)"

But this doesn't work.

So please help me out in this. 
If suppose i have to create a function in my JS controller function, then give me the function and syntax to call it in my html.

I will share my code, it will be useful to give me an update.

```
<p style="text-align: justify; white-space: nowrap; position: relative; left: 30px">
<strong>{{'EMAIL_TYPE' | translate}}</strong> 
<select id="emailOption" style="height: 26px; width: 190px; font-size: 13px; padding-top: 3px" class="emailType" data-ng-model="typeE" onchange="changeTemplate()">
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <option value="Alert Dashboard">{{'ALERT_DASHBOARD' | translate}}</option>
    <option value="Survey Launch">{{'SURVEY_LAUNCH' | translate}}</option>
    <option value="CSW Launch">{{'SCW_LAUNCH_TREATMENT' | translate}}</option>
    <option value="Survey Close Treatment">{{'SURVEY_CLOSE_TREATMENT' | translate}}</option>
    <option value="CSW Close">{{'CSW_CLOSE' | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

This is my dropdown values (options).

I wanted my text area to be disabled only if option value="" (null).

My code for textarea is.

```
<div class="large-9 medium-12 small-12 columns body1">
                            <strong style="position: absolute; left: 80px">{{'BODY_AT_BEGINNIG'
                                | translate}} </strong>

                            <textarea id="emailBody1" 
                                style="width: 70%; position: absolute; top: 15px; resize: none;"
                                rows="10" ></textarea>
```

Give me solution for this, so that my text area will be disabled only if my selected option from dropdown is null.

Comment: I'm assuming when you say: "I tried with ng-disabled='(here my ng-model value)' ", you mean `ng-disabled="typeE"`? Are these HTML elements in the same scope as your model that you're using?

Comment: yes. ng-disabled="typeE=' ' || typeE=null"
I tried with this code, and also ng-readonly="typeE=' ' || typeE=null"

Comment: I also tried ng-disabled="typeE=' ' && typeE=null"
Am i making any syntax error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just Try this

In the 'changeTemplate' method what you have called in ng-change, check whether the selected option value is null or not if it's null then disable your textarea like below

```
<div ng-app>
     <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl">
          <textarea ng-disabled="typeE == '' || typeE == null" id="emailBody1" style="width: 70%; position: absolute; top: 15px; resize: none;" rows="10" ></textarea>   
     </div>
</div>


function ClickToEditCtrl($scope)
{
     $scope.typeE = "";
}
```

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zakirshakir/5DMjt/7710/)

Comment: Its not working!!
The changetemplate helps in populating some texts when emailtype is selected.

Comment: Can you check with my condition which i tried,
ng-disabled="typeE=' ' "
and also ng-disabled="typeE=' ' && typeE=null".
Am i making any syntax error here.

Comment: just try this...
ng-disabled=" (typeE == ' ' || typeE == null) ?  true: false";

Comment: <textarea ng-disabled="(typeE==' ' || typeE == null)? true:false"; id="emailBody1" 
         style="width: 70%;  position: absolute; top: 15px; resize: none;"
         rows="10" ></textarea>

Like this? Am i correct here. any syntax mistakes?

Comment: This is working
<textarea ng-disabled="typeE == '' || typeE == null" id="emailBody1" style="width: 70%; position: absolute; top: 15px; resize: none;" rows="10" ></textarea>  

this the fidler link
http://jsfiddle.net/zakirshakir/5DMjt/7710/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zakirshakir/5DMjt/7716/    --- jsfiddle link(Working example)

Comment: Hi, Can you share me the code to disable the textarea onload using jquery(jqtw_editor). Share me like a function which i can define it in my controller and syntax to call it in my HTML. Please refer the above code where i used the function Change template(). In my html which has the functionality in my controller.

Comment: @s.sathish kumar if that is working pls upvote the comment.

Comment: In that function you need to check any condition?? Or just only disable the text area when you are calling that function????

Comment: Yes with the condition "typeE=='' || typeE== null".
FYI i already upvoted.

Comment: You can add above code what I have mentioned in the answer to inside
$scope.your_function_name = function () {add above code here};  and call it some where else in your controller like $scope.your_function_name ();  it will work when your page load

Comment: i cant get you, please specify with any function. It is same for the above code, onload i want the function to be called, at present it is calling only changeTemplate();

So add the function to disable the textarea onload. And share it

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your html code. It will do it. You really should use jade with angularjs.

```
<textarea id="emailBody1" , ng-disabled="typeE === '' ",
  style="width: 70%; position: absolute; top: 15px; resize: none;"
  rows="10" >
</textarea>
```

Don't forget to vote up ;)

Comment: Thanks mate. its working, with
<textarea id="emailBody1" , ng-disabled="typeE == '' ",
  style="width: 70%; position: absolute; top: 15px; resize: none;"
  rows="10" >
</textarea>

Comment: Hi, 
Can you share me the code to disable the textarea onload using jquery(jqtw_editor).
Share me like a function which i can define it in my controller and syntax to call it in my HTML. Please refer the above code where i used the function Change template(). In my html which has the functionality in my controller.